# Solving the transfer money logic

Tags: java, for-loop

I have some problem to solve, what is the algorithm you will use?

```
Payer:
John: 0.30
Paul: 0.50

Receiver
Ford: 0.10, Rafi: 0.10
Ryan: 0.50, Nico: 0.10

Result:
John 0.10 ->  Ford 0.10
John 0.10 ->  Rafi 0.10
John 0.10 ->  Ryan 0.10 (having problem here)
Paul 0.40 ->  Ryan 0.40 (having problem here)
Paul 0.10 ->  Nico 0.10
```

Incomplete Code:

```
    List<PayerList> payerList = new ArrayList<>();
    payerList.add(new PayerList(John, 0.30));
    payerList.add(new PayerList(Paul, 0.50));

    List<ReceiverList> receiverList = new ArrayList<>();
    receiverList.add(new ReceiverList(Ford, 0.10, Rafi, 0.10));
    receiverList.add(new ReceiverList(Ryan, 0.50, Nico, 0.10));

    List<Transfer> transfer = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PayerList payer: payerList) {
        double payerAmount = payer.getPayerAmount();
        for (ReceiverList receiver: receiverList) {
            if(payerAmount >= receiver.getFirstAmount()) {
                transfer.add(new Transfer(collected.getPayerAccount(), allocation.getReceiverAccount(), allocation.getFirstAmount()));
                payerAmount = payerAmount - allocation.getFirstAmount();
            }

            if(payerAmount >= receiver.getSecondAmount()) {
                transfer.add(new AccountTransfer(collected.getPayerAccount(), allocation.getReceiverAccount(), allocation.getFirstAmount()));
                payerAmount= payerAmount- allocation.getSecondAmount();
            }
        }
        // John still have 0.10, how to pay Ryan 0.10, before continue using Paul money
    }
```

Form the above code John still have 0.10, how to pay Ryan 0.10, before continue using Paul money to pay the remaining Ryan 0.40?

Comment: Hard to read; not sure what you're going for here.

Comment: What's the problem? Everything balances.  Unless that's the _expected_ output.  If so, please also show the ***actual*** output.

Comment: Maybe you should swap the loops. For receiver list, iterate over payers looking for first payer with available money. Edit: and also deal with the case where payer 1 can't cover the whole amount.

Comment: Note also that there are many "solutions", not just the one you indicated.  What happens if you start distributing Paul's 0.50 first?

Comment: @roby maybe is a better idea?

Comment: It's the same thing in the end I think. For each payer, pay as many recipients as you can. Or for each receiverList find payers.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking if payerAmount is greater than amount to be paid `if(payerAmount >= receiver.getFirstAmount())`  add else condition to check if payerAmount is still positve then pay the remaining amount